# After restoring minimized window it stays inactive (16.04 LTS)

Tags: unity, launcher, compiz, window

Weird problem - probably something to do with Compiz and its plugins.

Happens when I minimize a window, and restore it to its previous state by either clicking on the icon in the launcher. The window maximes but remains inactive, unresponsive, until I double-click the title bar and thus manually unmaximize/maximize it.

It would appear as if the panel bar is active over the window itself, hence the non-responsiveness. Can I fix that?

[image: I've tried to screenshot its appearance. It would appear as if the]

Comment: sounds like a bug. Would recommend submitting a bug report on Launchpad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug related to some conflicts in Compiz. I reinstalled Unity and reset compiz using

> dconf reset -f /org/compiz

followed by

> setsid unity.

It restarted the graphics interface and solved the problem.

Comment: You can accept your own answer by selecting the button on the left that is a checkmark, thereby marking your answer as 'resolved', if you wish to mark your own answer as the one that solved your issue.